# Always Open Link in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-api

I am trying to write the JavaScript code for a web page that will pop up a chart using the Google Charts API (which only works well in Internet Explorer).  Is there a way to automatically open the link in Internet Explorer regardless of the native browser being used to view the webpage?

Comment: The days of IE-only sites are ten years behind us.

Comment: Google Charts only works in IE?  Really?

Answer (score 3):

No; that's totally impossible.

And the Google Charts API works fine in other browsers.